# Facebook Tweaks with CocoaPods linker error when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, cocoapods

I added [Facebook Tweaks](https://github.com/facebook/Tweaks) to my project via CocoaPods and now I want to share the app with some tester via TestFlight. By default, Tweaks is deactivated in the Release build (which is used when archiving for distribution), so I did the following:

1. created a new scheme "MyApp TestFlight" by copying my original scheme
2. Added a Build configuration in the project  info screen, called "TestFlight" (in addition to the preconfigured "Debug" and "Release". When asked which configuration I wanted to inherit settings from I used the "Release" configuration.
3. In the "MyApp Testflight" scheme I set the build configuration to use for "Archive" to be "TestFlight".
4. In the preprocessor macros I defined different values for the macro `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED` which is used by the Facebook Tweaks Library to enable and disable it's usage. Since I surely don't want Tweaks enabled in the Release configuration (e.g. for the App Store) but I do want to be able to distribute an app with Tweaks enabled via TestFlight, I activated Tweaks in the Debug and TestFlight configurations, but not in the Release configuration.
   [image]
5. I verified that activating and deactivating Tweaks works by switching the `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED` between 0 and 1 in the Debug configuration.

So far everything works, I can activate an deactivate Tweaks using my preprocessor constant. I also verified, that using the different schemes to run changes the preprocessor constants as expected.

So I can successfully run the app with and without Tweaks enabled. But when I try to archive it, it fails with a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"__FBTweakIdentifier", referenced from:
  ___30-[SUPConfirmPaymentView setup]_block_invoke_2 in SUPConfirmPaymentView.o
  ___30-[SUPConfirmPaymentView setup]_block_invoke_254 in SUPConfirmPaymentView.o
  ___30-[SUPConfirmPaymentView setup]_block_invoke_277 in SUPConfirmPaymentView.o
  ___30-[SUPConfirmPaymentView setup]_block_invoke_2102 in SUPConfirmPaymentView.o
  ___30-[SUPConfirmPaymentView setup]_block_invoke_2125 in SUPConfirmPaymentView.o
  ___30-[SUPConfirmPaymentView setup]_block_invoke_2150 in SUPConfirmPaymentView.o
  ___30-[SUPConfirmPaymentView setup]_block_invoke_2171 in SUPConfirmPaymentView.o
  ...
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

There are more errors like this for armv7s and arm64.
But my project, as well as the target, as well as the libraries in the Pods project and the Pods project itself all have `Architctures` and `Valid Architectures` set to "arm64 armv7 armv7s".

For the record: My `SUPConfirmPaymentView setup` method does a lot of calls like this:

```
// setup animation constants
FBTweakBind(self, beatEnlargementFactor, @"Confirm Payment View", @"Beat Animation", @"scale factor", 1.1, 1.0, 3.0);
```

But I don't think that's the problem as it works in the debug builds and I guess it's just the first place the linker notices something is wrong.

So what does work:

- Run on simulator or device using DEBUG configuration which fas `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=1`
- Run on simulator or device using DEBUG configuration which fas `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=0`
- Archive using RELASE configuration which fas `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=0`
- Run on simulator or device using TestFlight configuration which has `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=0`
- Archive using TestFlight configuration which has `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=0`

What doesn't work

- Run on simulator or device using TestFlight configuration which has `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=1`
- Archive using TestFlight configuration which has `FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=1`

I don't understand why it doesn't work as it should be the same as the Release configuration (I copied it from that) and that does work, except for this one constant. And the debug build using that constant DOES work.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @alloy for pointing to this issue on CocoaPods: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1934#issuecomment-40132425
It seems to be related.

Therefore I used the following code from the issue discussion:

```
#if defined(DEBUG) && DEBUG
#warning DEBUG=1
#else
#warning DEBUG=0
#endif
```

And copied it to SUPConfirmPaymentView.m.

The result is this:

[image: build results with warnings when using code above]

By just pasting the code I already get a wring for Debug=1, which is due to Xcode's continuous compilation (which apparently uses the DEBUG flag). 
But when using Archive I get the results above and as far as I understand it, those warning below the Target all result from this one Archive build right? This would mean that the preprocessor (?) passes the .m-file twice, once with DEBUG=1 and once with Debug=0, which would explain the problem.
But this raises two other questions:

1. Why does it pass the .m file twice, should it just come by once as it's a .m-file (I see why that happens for .h files)
2. Why is DEBUG=1? Where does that come from?

**EDIT2:**
I recreated my "TestFlight" target to be a copy of the Debug target, as recommended by @alloy. It still doesn't build, which is likely due to CocoaPods not using the debug configuration.
How can I make it use the debug configuration? @alloy mentioned something about `:debug`, but I don't know how to use it and didn't find any documentation about it.
My current Podfile looks like this (project excluded):

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Tweaks'
```

How would I use the `:debug` syntax to make CocoaPods build the Tweaks library in the debug configuration when using it for my 'TestFlight' configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are running into this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1934#issuecomment-40132425.

(I’m not going to cross-paste a long answer and all of its context, it’s better if you read the issue on the ticket tracker.)

Comment: Not sure if I understood everything (e.g., I haven't spend time with the 'Beta' => :debug syntax yet, so I don't get what it does), as far as I understood it you are guessing that the Tweaks lib is compiled with DEBUG=0 (or undefined), which causes the actual implementation to be left out. But at the same time my project is compiled with DEBUG=1 which causes it to look for the implementation. Sounds like a good theory, that would explain the issue, but as you can see from the screenshot above, I am not setting the DEBUG flag, so it should still be undefined. Shouldn't it work in that case?

Comment: I copied the `#warning DEBUG=1` debugging code from the issues discussion to one of my .m files to see what's actually going on. I just don't know what to make from the results. It would be great if you could take a look (edited the questions accordingly).

Comment: If you actually want to have tweaks enabled in your archive build, then you should do it with a configuration that is based on a ‘debug’ config and you should tell CocoaPods to base the config of that name on `:debug` as well. Then you will have `DEBUG=1` in both configs and the missing symbols should be included.

Comment: I couldn't find any specification about the ":debug" syntax in the Podfile (checked here: guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#podfile ). How would I specify this in the Podfile? Sorry, I'm using Xcode configurations for the first time and can't seem to figure out how to tell CocoaPods what to do. I already recreated the "TestFlight" Configuration to inherit from Debug, so I think all that is missing is to do. I added my current Podfile to the question, could you maybe point out how to modify it using ':debug' to make CocoaPods compile the Tweaks library in the correct way?

Comment: It’s listed under the ‘xcode project config’ part of the Podfile doc: http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#xcodeproj.